# Grails + Tomcat6 + Multiple Instances + Shared Lib Folder

Tags: grails, tomcat6

I've got a Tomcat6 server that runs multiple Instances for two separate grail apps.
When I compile my WAR file for deployment normally

```
run-app -Dgrails.env=production war test.war
```

It deploys correctly and everything works as it is suppose too.
The problem is, I don't want the JAR files included in my WAR.

So I use the following command line instead

```
run-app -Dgrails.env=production war test.war --nojars
```

Now when my grails app deploys (it doesn't) I get a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

I have copied the lib folder (from my initial test.war) to the following locations

```
${catalina.base}/shared/lib
${catalina.home}/shared/lib
${catalina.home}/lib
```

None of these work.

My catalina.properties all point to the correct locations.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried putting the Grails JARs into your ${catalina.home}/lib directory?

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

1. BuildConfig.groovy has inherits global, which has the app inherit all of the grails/plugins dependencies.  If you change this, it may affect both your build and packaging - plus I have yet to encounter any documentation on what type of other things you can do with the inherits DSL
2. Grails deployment documentation suggests there is a way to customize which dependencies make it into the war file:  http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/17.%20Deployment.html
3. Event hooks give you access to provide a closure routine into various stages of the grails lifecycle.  Can it strip out framework jars from the final war? Haven't tried that either - only using it to re-write various config files for additional envrionment configuration.  However it does look like packaging events are exposed to this API:

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/4.%20The%20Command%20Line.html